# Java: Unpredictability with IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, do-while, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a script which works fine, as far as I have programmed it. Within that script, I have a do-while loop within which there are two more do-while loops, one feeding to the other.

I have removed some code for clarity:

```
StockArray.stockCodeArray();// creates stockcode array
FileArray.fileListArray();  // creates array of file names to input into
                            // ImportFiles
ImportFiles.importAscii();  // reads file. if debug: creates importarray

do {
    ObsHandler.obsPartsHandler(); // read part descriptions into temp
                                    // array
    ObsHandler.search();
} while (!endline.equals(null));
```

obsPartsHandler():

```
String numberline;
ObsHandler o1 = new ObsHandler("Part");
if (i < ImportFiles.importarray.size()) {
    do {
        numberline = ImportFiles.importarray.get(i); //editted here
        i = i + 1;
    } while (!numberline.startsWith(".Number"));

    i = i + 1; // set i to second line of part description
    do {
        i = i + 1; // set i to next line
    } while (!numberline.equals(""));

    if (i < ImportFiles.importarray.size()) {
        endline = ImportFiles.importarray.get(i);
        System.out.println(endline);
    }
}
```

All variables have been initialised. The search() method is currently blank.

As I go through the loops, there a print streams, that I have ommitted, which indicate that the loops are functioning correctly.

The problem I have is, when I run the program the OutOfBoundsException I am expecting from the if statement in obsPartsHandler is unpredictable in it's location on the console. I am wondering if, but still assuming that, this is something I have done wrong.

If I have removed too much code, please comment and I will add it back in.

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 307, Size: 307
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at ams.ObsoletePartsHandler.org.ObsHandler.obsPartsHandler(ObsHandler.java:58)
at ams.ObsoletePartsHandler.org.ObsHandler.main(ObsHandler.java:35)
```

Comment: @Pshemo your edit messed up the code... (`obsPartsHandler():` is not code).

Comment: Where is `numberLine` initialised/updated?

Comment: @Pshemo Now it looks like my edit, that came 2s after yours. So it's fine with me.

Comment: By the way, this is quite an unusual way to structure your loops. Wouldn't it be easier to have one `for` loop that ensures `i` never leaves the boundary with `break`s for various exit conditions?

Comment: @biziclop within the first do-while loop of obsPartsHandler, but that part of the code is working, and producing what I expect. Also, to your second comment, quite possibly, i'm quite new to Java.

Comment: `ams.ObsoletePartsHandler.org.ObsHandler.obsPartsHandler(ObsHandler.java:58)` Whats on line 58 in ObsHandler.java?

Comment: @SeanKenny Are you sure? Maybe you changed the file, you'll need to run it again. There is no `java.util.ArrayList.get` at that line, so it can't be where the exception was thrown.

Comment: @Ishtar No, that was my mistake:     numberline = ImportFiles.importarray.get(i);

Comment: @SeanKenny I don't see that line in the posted code?

Comment: @Ishtar Sorry, i'm new to this. I editted it in. (second do-while loops in obsPartsHandler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you worrying about where the exception message appears though? The user should never be faced with your debug prints nor stack traces from your exceptions.

Exception traces and regular prints are normally sent to two different output streams (System.err and System.out respectively), messages will not necessarily be synchronized between the two. `flush()`-ing the stream after printing to it may help. That said, if you are expecting the exception, you should probably either code to avoid it preemptively or catch it with Java's exception handling.

Comment: I'm worrying about it because I think it must represent an error in my code. That said, where I thought the exception was coming from turns out not to be right, so I'm going to have a rethink.

Comment: Exceptions do indicate errors in your code (or elsewhere), but having garbled console output when debugging them is pretty common! You only need worry about the exception itself, not how the console looks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (i < ImportFiles.importarray.size()) {
    do {
        numberline = ImportFiles.importarray.get(i);
        i = i + 1;
    } while (!numberline.startsWith(".Number"));
    //...
```

Let's assume `importarray` contains 3 lines: `aaa`,`foo` and `bar`. If `i` starts at `0`. What will happen?

It will set linenumer to `aaa` and test if it starts with ".Number" . Then set it to `foo`, set it to `bar`. Now the line is still not found, so `i` becomes `3`, but there is no 4th line, thus an exception is throw. (First item has index 0, so 4th item has index 3.)

You could make a function for those 4 lines of code that do what you need:

```
private int getLineStartsWith(List<String> list,String startsWith,int offset) {
    for (int k = offset; k < list.size(); k++)
        if (list.get(k).startsWith(starsWith);
             return k;//line found

    return -1;//line not found
}
```

Just return `-1` if the line is not found in the list. Then your function can be written as:

```
i = getLineStartsWith(ImportFiles.importarray,".Number",i);
if (i == -1)
   'Not found'
```

Comment: Whilst your time spent writing this answer is greatly appreciated, I think I have poorly explained the problem. The script works, in that it finds ".Number ...." and copies lines into ObsHandler.temp until it finds the next blank string. The problem I have lies in when the exception appears on the console, it appears in one of 3 places: at the end; just above an output of importarray or just below this output, with lines missing. My question was intended to try and find underlying errors in my code which would cause this anomalous behaviour.

Comment: @SeanKenny The exception is written to stderr, the normal output to stdout. The console prints the outputstreams interleaved. You could redirect stderr to `/dev/null`. So it wont be printed at all. But IMHO the error in your code is that it throws an exception.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I will have another look through it and post on here if I encounter problems again.